# Setup or env variable lost after running bash files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Please excuse me if there is an error in the sample code.

There are two files testA.sh and testB.sh.

testA.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

export a="hello"
source testb.sh
```

testB.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "test b"
echo $a
```

deepak[18:33] $ ./testA.sh
test b
hello

deepak[18:33] $ echo $a

deepak[18:33] $

If we run any setup in the testB.sh then how can we use that setup or env variable in the main console (for example echo $a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

testA.sh runs in a subshell, and it's environment evaporates with it when it ends.

if you `source testA.sh` it will keep the value.

```
$: ./testA.sh
test b
hello
$: echo $a

$: . ./testA.sh
test b
hello
$: echo $a
hello
```